# How to add an input field to specific select field with ng-options AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I am making a polling app using Angular and Node/Express/Mongo and would like to add a custom input field to add an option, when you select "I would like to add a custom option". I'm using ng-options to generate the voting options.

The HTML of the poll looks like this now: (poll is retrieved from database and added to $scope.poll.options:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>
            {{poll.title}}
          </h2>
          <h5>
            Created by: {{poll.displayName}}
          </h5>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="vote">I would like to vote for:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="vote" ng-model="poll.vote" ng-options="item.option as item.option for item in poll.options">
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="userID === poll.userID">
             <br>
               <label for="vote">Vote with my own option</label>
               <input ng-model="poll.vote" placeholder="Your own option" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="votePoll(poll)">Vote</button>
          </form>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400">
          </canvas> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

A vote is attached to $scope.poll.vote and I use that to hit an EditPoll controller that talks to an API to update database.

If you are a logged in user + at your own poll: you can select a custom option from the dropdown and that shows a blank input field to add an option. I can't figure out what the code should be for that, any suggestions???

So for example:

I would like to vote for:

- Option1
- Option2
- Option3
- I would like a custom option > shows a blank input field below

Answer (score 1):

Here you can bind custom drop down item with specific text input field using watch feature we can update drop down filed data dynamically.

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("FirstController",function($scope){
 
 
 $scope.items = [{
   id: 'opt_1',
   label: 'aLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
 }, 
 {
   id: 'opt_2',
   label: 'bLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
 }, 
 {
   id: 'opt_custom',
   label: 'I would like a custom option',
   subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
 }];
 
  $scope.checkOptions=function(){
   // alert($scope.selected.id);
    if($scope.selected.id=='opt_custom'){
 $scope.$watch('custom', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  debugger;
  $scope.items[2].id='opt_custom_'+$scope.custom;
  $scope.items[2].label=$scope.custom;
 });
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Simple App</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="FirstController">


<select ng-change="checkOptions()" ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>

 <input ng-model="custom" placeholder="Your own option" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```